# Mono for Android Visual Design for Visual Studio 10.0?

Tags: xamarin.android

I've installed Mono For Android Trial on my computer And I want to use with Visual Studio.
But there is a visual design for it or only I must write every thing ?
Thankyou for information
Piercarlo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No there is no visual designer included. You can however use the [Android Development Tools (ADT) Plugin for Eclipse](http://developer.android.com/sdk/eclipse-adt.html) which includes a Forms Designer to design your forms (granted you do need to install Eclipse for that) - the resulting XML you can just copy and paste into your monodroid project.

Comment: MMM... I think I will use directly eclipse for gratis

Answer (score 1):

Xamarin: As of Mono for Android 4.2 we now include an integrated UI Designer for creating Android layout resources in either MonoDevelop or Visual Studio.